# Two coins are tossed together . Find $P(A/B) $ if $A=$Tail appears on one coin , $B=$ One coin shows head.

Tags: probability

Two coins are tossed together . Find $P(A/B) $ if $A=$Tail appears on one coin , $B=$ One coin shows head.

My solution goes as follows:

> $P(A\cap B)=\frac{2}{4}$  and $P(B)=\frac{2}{4}$ . So, $P(A/B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=1$ .

However , I am confused about two "different senses of B". One one hand , B may imply head appears on " only one coin" and on the other hand it may imply head appears on "anyone of the coins" and may appear on both of them. Then in the former case $P(B)=\frac{2}{4}$ and in the later case $P(B)=\frac{3}{4}$. If $P(B)=\frac{3}{4}$, then $P(A/B)=\frac{2}{3}$. So which is the valid case? Does the answer depends upon the two senses mentioned above? Why the other one is not valid? Where is the problem occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis nailed it, for the *most* part.

The correct answer depends entirely on your interpretation of the phrase : "*One coin shows head*".

This might reasonably be interpreted in $3$ different ways, two of which you discussed:

$\underline{\text{Interpretation-1 : Exactly one coin shows head}}$ 
Then, there must be exactly one coin with Tails, so the probability = 1.

$\underline{\text{Interpretation-2 : At least one coin shows head}}$ 
Then, out of the $4$ equally likely scenarios, the only one that has been eliminated is having two tails.  Therefore, the equally likely scenarios remaining are

HH, HT, TH. 
So, the probability of one tail is $(2/3).$

$\underline{\text{Interpretation-3 : A specific coin shows heads}}$ 
This is the scenario that you did not discuss.  In this scenario, a specific coin (for example, the oldest coin)
has been declared to be heads.

Then, since the youngest coin showing tails is an independent event from the oldest coin showing heads, the probability of the youngest coin being tails is $(1/2)$.

---

The resolution of interpretation-1 should not seem counter intuitive.  If that is the intent of the constraint, then there has to be 1 tails.

The challenge is to stretch your intuition to understand  why the 2nd and 3rd interpretations would give different results.

The 3rd interpretation reflects that only one coin was inspected (e.g. the oldest coin), and that coin was seen to be heads.  This information in no way impacts the question of whether the youngest coin is heads.

The 2nd interpretation reflects an entirely different scenario.  Here, both coins were inspected, and it was noted that the (1/4) probability that both coins were tails did not occur.

Since the scenario that prompted the 2nd interpretation is different from the scenario that prompted the 3rd interpretation, it is not that counter-intuitive that the interpretations should yield different probabilities.

---

This begs the question: if you know that the first interpretation is not intended, then what is the correct answer?

There is no way to tell, because you don't know how the information was gathered that allowed it to be declared that *one coin is heads*.  Was it because one specific coin was examined and seen to be heads, or was it because both coins were examined and seen to not both be tails?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the problem depends on the interpretation of $B$.

Your calculations are right, I think you need to discuss the problem with the person who proposed it to you.

Answering your questions:

- I would interpret $B$ as "*head appears on anyone of the coins*"
- The answer absolutely depends on how you pick $B$, as your calculations stated.
- Both cases are possible, depending on the interpretation of the events. This follows from the interpretation of conditional probability: $P(A|B)$ means "the probability that $A$ will happen knowing that $B$ has happened." So if $B$ is the "only one head came up" event, if you flip two coins it is mandatory that the other one is tails, hence that the probability $P(A|B)=1$. Otherwise, as by your math, it is not $1$.

---

An observation: you wrote $P(A/B)$ for conditional probability, but is $P(A|B)$